# make all images the same size in a slideshow

Tags: html, css

im trying to make all the images in a slideshow be of same size, I've tried using

```
.slideshow-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

but doesn't work

Comment: this will set them to 100% of the parent container. Instead of percent try 300px or try the css 'max-width' or 'max-height'

Comment: "same size" => which size? Please post a lot more code like the markup including slideshow-container and the CSS for all those elements, as a snippet here or else static code here and a link to a fiddle/codepen (not just a link to latter).

Answer (score 1):

I would first start out with adding this to your css

```
body,html{
height: 100%;
```

}

Then I would create a parent element to basically contain all of the images

```
<div class='container'> <!-- your images --> </div>
```

Then just set the width of that to say 500px by 500px

Finally, you should be able to use height & width at 100%

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.2').click(function(){
      $('.img1').css("display","none");
      $('.img2').css("display","block");
  });
  $('.3').click(function(){
      $('.img2').css("display","none");
      $('.img3').css("display","block");
  });
});

// not a very good example of how to make a slideshow but its more to show how to make images the same size as opposed to having a working slideshow
```

```css
body,html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.img1{
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/284951/pexels-photo-284951.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}
.img2{
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/397998/pexels-photo-397998.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    display: none;
}
.img3{
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/376533/pexels-photo-376533.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="img1"></div>
  <div class="img2"></div>
  <div class="img3"></div>
</div>

  <button class="1">Img 1</button>
  <button class="2">Img 2</button>
  <button class="3">Img 3</button>
<!--
Photo by Timotej Nagy from Pexels https://www.pexels.com/photo/dark-gold-lamp-light-284951/

-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full screen slider, it's going to be something more complicated than that. Try this:

```css
.slideshow-container {
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
.slideshow-container img {
  max-width:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
  }
```

I would also recommend to check examples. From here maybe:

[Link](https://corpocrat.com/2015/12/09/20-cool-pure-css-sliders-without-jqueryjavascript/)